# How to create dropdownlist with static and dynamic values in Asp.net MVC with a divider between them

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2

I want to create a dropdownlist which have three static values: Select All, Text Only, Numeric only. After that I like to add a line with some padding (just to separate these options) and then add some dynamic options.

I am not sure how to do this, Can some body please help?

So far I have created a `List<SelectListItem>` in my view model, and populated the static values from BLL. But I am not sure how to add a divider line in the middle now, and append some dynamic options after that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal select tag will not work like that, you will have to create custom dropdown using spans or divs.

See some examples here:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any examples which I can look at?

Comment: see here custom style dropdown is made using ul and li tags